# Difficulty separating my Jquery into a separate js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thank you in advance for any help.  I poured over similar questions here on SO and still can't figure it out.

I have an HTML file where I'm calling two functions that I've saved to a separate JS in the same directory as my HTML file.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="translate_game.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {

button_fun();
text_box_fun();

    });

</script>
```

My JS file translate_game.js:

```
$(function() {



        button_fun = function(){
            $("#basic_button").click(function(){ 
              $("#currentspanish").css("color", "yellow");
             });
         };


        text_box_fun = function(){
           $('#entry').focus(function(){
              $("#currentspanish").css("color", "red");

          });
        };

    });
```

When I refresh my HTML, the console tells me: Uncaught ReferenceError: button_fun is not defined

Is it obvious to anyone why this function can't be found?

Thank you!
Dan

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to define your functions that way, just use the traditional method. It's possible your functions aren't defined by the time your other function runs.

translate_game.js:

```
function button_fun(){
    $("#basic_button").click(function(){ 
       $("#currentspanish").css("color", "yellow");
    });
}
function text_box_fun(){
    $('#entry').focus(function(){
        $("#currentspanish").css("color", "red");
    });
}
```

Comment: The functions are being assigned to *globals*. This isn't the problem.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Maybe it's more likely they aren't defined by the time the other function runs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments back! I think I'm all set.

Answer (score 0):

$(function(){}); is a kind of shorthand syntax for $(document).ready(function(){});

Since you are just defining your functions in translate_game.js, you could remove the $(function(){}) wrapper. Since these scripts are loaded synchronously, the functions in translate_game.js will become available for your document.ready callback in your script tag.

If you want to maintain privacy or modularity, you can use a [revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript).

Also you should get into the habit of using 'var' to define variables, otherwise they become global. Yes, these will be in the global scope anyways, but you should develop a good habit.